# Click event on <div> not firing on Firefox but fires on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a click event on a div `feedbackInput`

```
<div id="feedbackInput" class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text mr-2"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input disabled class="form-control feedback-input" placeholder="Feedback about this page?" style="">
</div>
```

I added a click event like so:

```
$("#feedbackInput").click(function(e) {
    console.log("clicked")
});
```

I tested on Chrome and this works fine, i can't seem to figure out why this simple code doesn't work on FireFox.

If possible, i want to avoid using `onclick()` on the HTML element.

Anyone know why this doesn't work on Firefox?

Comment: That should work. Something else is the problem. What does the console say?

Comment: Have you imported jQuery?

Comment: Yes worked for me just fine as well. You may not have imported jQuery as Jack said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireFox won't accept the `click` event on the `disabled input` only

but `<div class="input-group-prepend">` works fine

[image]

**Use READONLY instead**

Comment: Good call, i ended up just making the button into a div, `<div class="form-control feedback-input" style="">Feedback about this page?</div>` issue was that the input was disabled. Reference for anyone in the future: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled